# How does adding two comments to a question affect deletion?

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions

> [[Source:]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#comment260975_92006) And the OP can prevent a question from being deleted by making two comments to the question.

The comment above was upvoted 39 times, but to which questions does it apply?

I can see that the comment applies to [questions > 365 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/226001), but what about questions ≤ 365 days?

Comment: No, they mean "And the OP can prevent a question from being deleted **by the automatic process** by making two comments to the question."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has **no effect** on questions less than or equal to 365 days.

The comment refers to the `If the question is more than 365 days old` part where it says `has 1 or 0 comments` - the commenter is saying if the OP adds 2 comments to his own question then it won't be subject to deletion **after 365 days**, *however* it may still be deleted if it meets all the conditions under the 30 days or 9 days policies, or a moderator deletes it, or enough high rep users vote to delete.

Basically - it can be deleted just as normal, but just not automatically under the 365 days policy.